# how to get minute of the system time from C program

Tags: c

how to get minute of the system time from C program? can I use gettimeoftheday?? If anyone has C program which can do this please share, I'm a newbie.Thanks

some sample code

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[30];
  struct timeval tv;

  time_t curtime;



  gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
  curtime=tv.tv_sec;

  strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
  printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);

  return 0;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strftime to get only the minutes part :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[0x100];
  time_t curtime;

  // Don't forget to check the return value !
  curtime = time(NULL);
  if (curtime == -1)
  {
    perror("time()");
    return 1;
  }

  strftime(buffer,0x100,"%M",localtime(&curtime));
  printf("minutes: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

No need to use gettimeofday here, use it only if you want a precision better than seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t curtime;
    char buffer[30];
    struct tm* tm_info;

    time(&curtime);
    tm_info = localtime(&curtime);

    strftime(buffer, 30, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm_info);
    puts(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

%Y:- will print year
%m:- will print Month
%d:- will print day
%H:- will print Hour
%M:- will print Minute
%S:- will print Second